# Alcatel One Touch Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, alcatel

Original Question:

Добрый день! Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли обновить телефон Alcatel OT-710 на Ubuntu через официальную программу обновления?

Translated to English:

Good day! I would like to see if you can update your phone Alcatel OT-710 through the official Ubuntu software updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. One Touch Upgrade is designed just for Windows.
Why you don't upgrade via OTA? (Settings > About phone > Upgrade)